Laravel Idea type-hints ids as int even if using UUIDs
Could not find any information on this issue.

I'm using PhpStorm's Laravel Idea plugin for my Laravel projects.
All of our models use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;, and our migrations use $table->uuid('id')->primary().
All of our foreign keys are char(36) as our migrations use $table->foreignIdFor(ParentModel::class); // 'parent_model_id' char(36)
When I run "Code Generation" ⌘⇧, the resulting helper files (found in "vendor/_laravel_idea/ide_helper_models*.php") hint that the model property type is int|null :

/**
 * ...
 * @property int|null $parent_model_id
 * ...
 */
 class ChildModel extends Model {}

Laravel Idea assumes the primary keys will be an int, and that's rarely the case in modern apps. This results in PhpStorm providing the wrong type-hint, and running PHPStan throws a type-mismatch when doing any comparisons or testing. In order to kludge fix this, I manually add my own phpdoc directly on my model. Though this has the effect of hampering PhpStorm, because now when I cmd+click into the property throughout my app, it will direct me to my PHPDoc declaration and not intelligently find the symbol references like it normally would.
Is there a setting somewhere to have Laravel Idea look at the actual migration or model definitions to set the type?

(note: not using Laravel Idea myself) I'd suggest to Laravel Idea Issue Tracker: https://github.com/laravel-idea/plugin/issues and create a new one if needed. Maybe similar workaround can be applied here: https://github.com/laravel-idea/plugin/issues/715 Although (logically thinking) this is pretty standard and should would out of the box.

I'm not familiar with that particular helper method, but try protected $keyType = 'string';  in your model. UUID might also be a possibility, but I'm not sure if it's implemented.

Indeed, it's much better to use https://github.com/laravel-idea/plugin/issues for this.
Laravel Idea uses ParentModel::$keyType and tries to find the type there. It seems you have "int" there. That's why the result type is also "int".

Thanks for the github suggestion. As to $keyType, all of our models return 'string'. The Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids trait handles this for you. Indeed, outputting $model->getKeyType() on any model with that trait returns 'string'. Good thought though. I'll shoot this over to the Laravel Idea folks.
